# Maria-db concurrent insert data loss issue

Tags: mysql, sql, concurrency, mariadb, innodb

I am facing a data loss issue when trying to insert data via multiple batch job.
We have `10.1.21-MariaDB-1~jessie` version with InnoDB as the default storage engine.

I have faced the following scenario where :

Column value is missing though value was present in generated insert statement for one of the record from the database.

Table auto incremented index value shows number `170`, but the actual record count was `165`. So here 5 records were lost completely .

Can anyone guide me on this to fix this issue ?

Comment: What is the source of the data?  This sounds like maybe you used a corrupted/badly formatted flat file.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen Source of data is batch text files and data format is correct , i tried some of those file individually and it works as per expectation.

Comment: Show the code of the batch job.

Answer (score 0):

Case 1:  You have outside knowledge of 5 particular rows being missing.  Need more info to discuss this one.

Case 2:  `COUNT(*)` says 165 but `SHOW TABLE STATUS` says 170 "Rows".  Don't trust the `STATUS`; it is an estimate.

Case 3:  You did a bunch of `INSERTs`, `COUNT(*)` says 150, `SHOW CREATE TABLE` says `AUTO_INCREMENT = 170`.  This says that some ids were "burned".  All types of `INSERT` statements (multi-row, IGNORE, IODKU, REPLACE, ROLLBACK, etc) have ways of burning ids.  Live with it.  If you describe your statements, we can go into more detail.

Comment: Batch execution has multiple files and those jobs runs concurrently . If I execute particular job having 170 rows then it works fine and all records get inserted properly.  And in another scenario where for particular record column value is missing but another similar record get inserted ( from same file ) properly with same value .

Comment: @Sachin - Too much hand-waving; specifics, please.

Answer (score 0):

My bad .... There was no such concurrency issue. In one of the scenario batch job was removing some records. And those job executions were not sequential , after proper sequential job chaining able to trace this issue.